# Problems with Apache redirect

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I defined an alias for a folder:

```
Alias /folder /var/www/vhost/folder
```

Now I have to redirect an image folder within the alias, so I wrote following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteBase /folder   
RewriteRule ^fileadmin/(.*)$ /folder/fileadmin/$1
```

In theory that should work, but  I do get following in the apache error log:

```
File does not exist: /var/www/null/fileadmin, referer: http://domain.tld/folder/
```

Anyone ideas, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: FYI: `RewriteBase /folder` will only affect the **URL** part, not the physical path on disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the result of rewrite to the other handlers (Alias) using the `[PT]` flag. See answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334111/how-to-use-apache-mod-rewrite-and-alias-at-the-same-time) for more info